# Python code does not write log directly with a Run but logs when doing a Run And Debug in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Python code stopped writing log to a log file when using Run option which was happening till yesterday (not sure what changed), same code writes log when using 'Run and Debug' option.

logging config as below-
import logging
import requests

logging.basicConfig(filename='validation.log', filemode='a', level=logging.ERROR, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s',datefmt='%H,%M,%S')

calling the logging.error as below-

logging.error(f"Server: {server} - Success! end point is accessible. Response Code: {response_getwave.status_code}\n")

I have tried using Run and Debug which writes the log as expected.
I am using the standard logging.basicConfig module within python

Comment: Can you elaborate on whether the **Run** you are using is `Run Code` or `Run Python File`?

Comment: sorry @MingJie-MSFT, saw this late, and apologies, the issue was a wrong log argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue stands resolved, the logging argument with logging.BasicConfig  was incorrectly formed and that prevented the logs from getting written.